# How TextBox is shown when user select other from DropDownList in web forms using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have `asp:DropDownList` and my requirement is when user select other from list a `TextBox` is shown to user. But initially `TextBox` is hidden.

I write below code to hide `TextBox` when page is loaded.

```
txtOtherArea.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none")
```

But when I try to show this `TextBox` using JQuery, nothing happened. Below is my JQuery code.

```
$(function () {
    $("#ddlUserArea").click(function () {
        $("#txtOtherArea").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

I also try to use `show()` instead of `fadeIn("slow")` but there is no option to use `show()` method.

Then I try below code to hide `TextBox` initially.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtOtherArea").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    </script>
```

I write above code in head section of Master page. But nothing happened.

I read other topics and question on this forum but don't understand may be because of much complexity. I am new in programming and just need to show `TextBox` when user select Other from `DropDownList`. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use magic string for id, instead use `ClientID` generated by asp.net for your controls :

```
var ddlUserArea = "<%=ddlUserArea.ClientID %>";
var txtOtherArea = "<%=txtOtherArea.ClientID %>";
```

and for dropdown you have to use change event:

```
$("#"+ddlUserArea).change(function () {
        $("#"+txtOtherArea).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Ehsan, I write below code.

$(function () {
    var ddl = $("#<%=ddlUserArea.ClientID%>");
    var txt = $("#<%=txtOtherArea.ClientID%>");
    $("#"+ddl).change(function () {
        if(ddl.val()=="11")
        {
            alert("I am alert");
            $("#" + txt).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
});

But it doesn't work. Even alert is not show.

Comment: As I said I am new in this field. I have no idea how to check browser console for any js errors. But I put '$(function () {
            $("#ddlUserArea").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == "11") {
                    alert("dfdf");
                }
            });'
Code direct in master page under script tag then it work fine. I can't understand why it doesn't work when I put this code in js file. I use ClientID as you said.

Comment: if you are using chrome browser press ctrl+shift+i and then from menu find Conole and click it and then reload page and observe console for js errors

Comment: Yes it shows two errors, and both are : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: change drop down selection and then observe console

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using server side id of control, you should use client side id as shown below.

```
$(function () {
    $("#ddlUserArea").click(function () {//YOU SHOULD USE .change() instead
        $("#<%=txtOtherArea.ClientID%>").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

**BETTER APPROACH**

```
$(function () {
    var ddl=$("#<%=ddlUserArea.ClientID%>");
    var txt=$("#<%=txtOtherArea.ClientID%>");
    ddl.change(function () {
        if(ddl.val()=="Other"){
            txt.fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
});
```